# How to properly use malloc() to store many integer values?

Tags: c, eclipse

I am having trouble using `malloc()`. Basically I want to store pixel information from a bitmap (assuming RGB `0-255` - though storing that as in int from `fgetc()` so we can still obtain the `EOF` indicator). I want it to be stored dynamically because I need to alter specific bits before sending it to an output. I have no idea why this code is failing but it just appears to either hang in the while loop or exit with a value of `-1` (possibly a seg fault).

```
int** outputbytes = (int **) malloc(writablesize*sizeof(char));
if (outputbytes == NULL)
    printf("mallocfailed");
int i = 0;
while(i < writablesize)
{
    int cbmp = fgetc(fbmp);
    if(cbmp == EOF)
        break;
    outputbytes[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    *outputbytes[i] = cbmp;
    i++;
}
```

EDIT: was just an error in logic and implementing malloc() in terms of the size. This is the working code thanks for helping

```
// Copy bmpdata to to dynamic memory
long* outputbytes = malloc(writablesize*sizeof(long));
if (outputbytes == NULL) exit(1); // Terminate if allocation fails
int opbi = 0; // Index for the output bytes
while(opbi < writablesize)
{
    int cbmp = fgetc(fbmp);
    outputbytes[opbi] = (long) cbmp;
    opbi++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int** outputbytes = (int **) malloc(writablesize*sizeof(char));   //sizeof(char ) ??
```

This is not correct (*not sufficient memory to hold* `int *`'s) .

You need to allocate memory for number of `int *` but you allocate for number of `char`'s . Do as this -

```
int** outputbytes = malloc(writablesize*sizeof(int *));
```

Now this allocate memory for `writablesize` number of `int *` and then this in `while` loop-

```
 outputbytes[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));  //allocating memory -sizeof(char) ??
```

Allocate memory equal to `sizeof(int)` to hold an integer,as it is an `int *` .

```
 outputbytes[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

**Note**- Don't cast result of `malloc` . Also remember to `free` allocated memory.

Comment: This doesn't help much, since it will do no good to store a bitmap in a fragmented lookup-table to begin with. It has to be stored in adjacent memory.

Comment: Yep this is what I really needed - I was just not really concentrating obviously and so put this line
int** outputbytes = (int **) malloc(writablesize*sizeof(char)); when in reality what i needed was int * outputbytes = malloc(writablesize*sizeof(int)); then each location in outputbytes will be able to store my bitmap data

Comment: @zacroker So , you need a pointer to `int` not pointer to pointer to `int` .

Comment: @ameyCU yep i've got it working as follows  
// Copy bmpdata to to dynamic memory
 long* outputbytes = malloc(writablesize*sizeof(long));
 if (outputbytes == NULL) exit(1); // Terminate if allocation fails
 int opbi = 0; // Index for the output bytes
 while(opbi < writablesize)
 {
  int cbmp = fgetc(fbmp);
  outputbytes[opbi] = (long) cbmp;
  opbi++;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating a memory for the variable outputbytes in two times in your code. You can allocate a memory for a single time for the outputbytes variable.

Then you are using the (sizeof(char)) for memory allocating for a integer variable. So, you are getting a segmentation fault error.

Then you are declaring a variable outputbytes as pointer to pointer. But you are trying to  accessing that variable as a pointer to an array.

So you can modify your code like below.

```
int** outputbytes = (int **) malloc(writablesize*sizeof(int));
if (outputbytes == NULL)
    printf("mallocfailed");
int i = 0;
while(i < writablesize)
{
    int cbmp = fgetc(fbmp);
    if(cbmp == EOF)
        break;
    *(outputbytes+i) = cbmp;  //Accessing pointer to a pointer
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using some sort of fragmented lookup table to store bitmaps, they need to be stored in adjacent memory cells. Therefore you need to rewrite your whole code so that it uses one single malloc.

You can either use malloc to allocate one single big chunk of bytes, or you can use it to allocate an array of struct items, in which case you must ensure that there is no unwanted padding in the struct.

Typically, bit maps are allocated through a bitmap header where the last item in a "flexible array member" which in turn will correspond to the bitmap data.

Anyway, what you really need to do is to get/make a header file that defines the bitmap format used and then take it from there.

Comment: yes that is obviously the best thing to do I'll just go ahead and rewrite my whole code... Those things have already been defined but I need this malloc to perfom some bitwise operations on the individual bytes (sequentially) of the bitmap